# In Excel, how do I automatically count entries made corresponding to every month?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In following Excel sheet, there are dates in column  `A2:A23` in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`. In `B2:B23` days are written using formula `=TEXT(A2,"ddd")`. In column `C2:C23` entries "Y" or "N" are made. The entries have been made for every month from October 2016 to March 2017 in column `C`. How I can automatically write all the months from range `A2:A23`, say for example in column `E` and display number of "Y/N" entries corresponding to every month?

For example, I want to see result like given in columns `E` and `F`. The entries in `E` and `F` are manually filled, but I want to fill these entries automatically.

I am aware of formula like `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2:A23)=MONTH(E)))`, but for this, I need to manually write months in column `E` from `A2:A23`.

```
+------------+-----+------------+--+-------+---------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|    Date    | Day | Entry(Y/N) |  | Month | Number of Y/N |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+------------+-----+------------+--+-------+---------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| 15-10-2016 | Sat | Y          |  | Oct   |             4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 17-10-2016 | Mon | Y          |  | Nov   |             5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 19-10-2016 | Wed | Y          |  | Dec   |             5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 23-10-2016 | Sun | Y          |  | Jan   |             4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 01-11-2016 | Tue | Y          |  | Feb   |             2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 05-11-2016 | Sat | N          |  | Mar   |             2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11-11-2016 | Fri | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15-11-2016 | Tue | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 22-11-2016 | Tue | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 05-12-2016 | Mon | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 09-12-2016 | Fri | N          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11-12-2016 | Sun | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 23-12-2016 | Fri | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 26-12-2016 | Mon | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 02-01-2017 | Mon | N          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 08-01-2017 | Sun | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10-01-2017 | Tue | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 22-01-2017 | Sun | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 08-02-2017 | Wed | N          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10-02-2017 | Fri | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11-03-2017 | Sat | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15-03-2017 | Wed | Y          |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|            |     |            |  |       |               |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+------------+-----+------------+--+-------+---------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

**Update:** Let me explain what I did. In `E2` I have written `=A2` and formatted this cell using custom format mmm which helped me to display `Oct` in `E2`, in `E3` I have used formula `=DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2)+1,DAY(E2))`, this formula helped me to display Nov in `E3` and so on. In `F2` I have written `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)))` which has given count 4, and subsequently in `F3` I have written `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)+1))`, in `F4 =SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)+2))` and so on. All is good till `Dec`, after that zero result is displayed for `Jan`, `Feb` and `March`. I think the increment in command =SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)+1)) is giving me errored result after `Dec`, which of course does not produce Jan when an increment is given month `Dec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In column E in E2 if your dates start in A2 write:
`=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"mm"))`
and drag it down till E23 last date
Select all E2:E23 copy paste special values in F2 (it will become F2:F23) 
delete column E select E2:E23(the new months)
Data Tab, Remove Duplicates (just from column E do not expand selection)
You will have each month once,in F2 write your formula:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=E2))`(Array Formula)
If you want to count only "Y" for each month use:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=VALUE(F2))*(--($C$2:$C$23="Y")))` (Array Formula)
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after both formulas and you can drag it

You can just use a formula directly in column D for example:
In D2 write (just in D2):
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)))`
In D3
`=IF(MONTH(A3)<>MONTH(A2),SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A3))),"")`
Also array formulas and drag it down
When the month change it will give the count
**Update**
Concerning your comment you can still use your formula:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(E2)))`
E2 not A2
If you wrote in E2 =A2 it means E2 is still a Date
and you can use Month(E2)
But you have to insert the criteria for the Year unless if you don't have the same month in 2016 and 2017
**Because January is affected by empty cells**
Use the following formula it will do the same work as the above one but also test if the cell is empty:
`=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$23<>"",IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(E2),1,0),0))`
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> array formula and drag it
If will return 1 if the Month(A2:A23)=Month(E2)
And 0 if empty or different
Sum will add 1

Comment: I need to automatically start writing month from `E2` onward in the format `Oct`, `Nov`,...etc. The first month should be linked with cell A2 and there should be a continuous increment in the month till `March`. In `F` column I need to count of "Y/N" from column `C` which should be exactly placed in front of each month in column `E`. The way you suggest to remove duplicate text valued month in `E` is manual one.

Comment: Let me explain to you what I did. In `E2` I have written `=A2` and formatted this cell using custom format `mmm` which helped me to display `Oct` in `E2`, in `E3` I have used formula `=DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2)+1,DAY(E2))`, this formula helped me to display `Nov` in `E3` and so on. In `F2` I have written `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)))` which has given count `4`, and subsequently in `F3` I have written `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)+1))`, in `F4` `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)+2))` and so on. All is good till `Dec`, after that zero result is displayed for

Comment: (.....Continued) `Jan`, `Feb` and `March`. I think the increment in command `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(A2)+1))` is giving me errored result after `Dec`, which of course does not produce `Jan` when an increment is given month `Dec`.

Comment: If you have a date in E2 and you just Custom Format the Date to show name of the month you can use Month(E2)

Comment: You can still use `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(E2)))`

Comment: Answer accepted due to the argument: "But you have to insert the criteria for the Year unless if you don't have the same month in `2016` and `2017` ". This was the error due which after `Dec`, zero results is displayed for `Jan`, as I was not changing year along with month.

Comment: My problem has been solved almost completely. But in formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(E2)))`,  if I change range `A2:A23` to `A2:A26`, then count for `Jan-2018` is displayed as 7 instead of 4 (additional 3 came from blank entries beyond `A23`). Rest of `Feb-2018` and `Mar-2018` are correct. Can we manipulate in this situation?

Comment: You can use another formula to test empty "" in this case it will not affect Jan count use `=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$23<>"",IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(E2),1,0),0))` it will sum only if the month is the same 1, else 0

Comment: The formula `=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$23<>"",IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$23)=MONTH(E2),1,0),0‌​))` contains error.

Comment: Array formula press Ctrl+Shift+Enter at the same time

Answer (score 1):

### Two approaches:

#### Messy formula:

Set `E2` to `=A2`. 
Set `E3` to

```
=IF(OR(E2=0,E2=""), "", MIN(IF(A$2:A$23>=DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2)+1,1), A$2:A$23, "")))
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
Drag/fill this down. 
This will initially produce

```
15-Oct-2016
1-Nov-2016
5-Dec-2016
2-Jan-2017
8-Feb-2017
11-Mar-2017
0-Jan-1900
```

(Here I have formatted the cells as the built-in `14-Mar-2012` format,
which is implemented as `[$-409]d-mmm-yyyy;@`.) 
`E2` clearly is `A2`, the first date. 
Then `DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2)+1,1)` evaluates to 1-Nov-2016;
the first day of the month following the date in `E2`. 
And finally, the complete formula in `E3` (given above)
finds the lowest/earliest (MINimum) date in `A2:A23` that’s ≥ this date. 
Somewhat confusingly, this is 1-Nov-2016, as that is on your list of dates. 
But `E4` is 5-Dec-2016, because that’s the lowest date ≥ 1-Dec-2016.

`E8` looks for the lowest date ≥ 1-Apr-2017. 
There aren’t any, so we get `MIN("")`,
which evaluates to 0, which displays as 0-Jan-1900. 
This is why the formula starts with `IF(OR(E2=0,E2=""), "", …`
— to prevent the formula from tying itself in knots. 
If you change the display format for Column `E` to `[$-409]mmm yyyy;;`
(deleting the initial `d-`, (optionally) changing the second `-` to a space,
and changing the final `@` to a second `;`), you’ll get

```
Oct 2016
Nov 2016
Dec 2016
Jan 2017
Feb 2017
Mar 2017
```

This suppresses the display of the day of the month,
and totally suppresses the display of the Jan-1900 entry.

#### Two helper columns:

Set `M1` to `=DATE(YEAR(A2), MONTH(A2), 1)`. 
Set `N2` to `=N1+COUNTIF(M$2:M$23, E2)`. 
Set `E2` to `=IFERROR(SMALL(M$2:M$23, N1+1), "")`. 
Drag/fill down. 
Column `M` must be dragged down to Row 23;
the other two only need to go far enough to generate the distinct months. 
This gives us

```
+----+------------+------------+-----+
|    |     E      |     M      |  N  |
+----+------------+------------+-----+
|  1 |            |            |     |
|  2 | 1-Oct-2016 | 1-Oct-2016 |  4  |
|  3 | 1-Nov-2016 | 1-Oct-2016 |  9  |
|  4 | 1-Dec-2016 | 1-Oct-2016 | 14  |
|  5 | 1-Jan-2017 | 1-Oct-2016 | 18  |
|  6 | 1-Feb-2017 | 1-Nov-2016 | 20  |
|  7 | 1-Mar-2017 | 1-Nov-2016 | 22  |
|  8 |            | 1-Nov-2016 | 22  |
|  9 |            | 1-Nov-2016 | 22  |
| 10 |            | 1-Nov-2016 | 22  |
| 11 |            | 1-Dec-2016 | 22  |
| 12 |            | 1-Dec-2016 | 22  |
                  |     ︙     |  ︙  |
```

where Column `M` tracks Column `A`
and Column `N` just repeats the total number of days in your spreadsheet.

Column `M` clearly shows the first day of the month
of the corresponding date in Column `A`.
`E2` is the smallest of these values; `SMALL(M$2:M$23, 1)`.
`N2` counts the dates in Column `M` that are equal to this value
(there are 4 dates in October) and adds it to `N1`,
which is blank (i.e., zero). 
(You can put an explicit `0` in `N1` if you want.) 
Then `E3` is the 5th smallest date, `SMALL(M$2:M$23, 5)`. 
And so on. 
And, of course, you can again format Column `E`
to suppress the display of the day of the month.

It occurs to me, after I’ve typed all of the above,
that I could have done this with `INDEX` instead of `SMALL`.

#### Note

Both of the above solutions
list only the months that are present in Column `A`. 
For example,
if Column `A` has dates in Oct 2016, Nov 2016, Dec 2016, Feb 2017 and Mar 2017
(but not Jan 2017),
then Column `E` will list Oct 2016, Nov 2016, Dec 2016, Feb 2017 and Mar 2017
(but not Jan 2017). 
I did this because the question says,
“How I can automatically write all the months from range `A2:A23`, …?” 
If you want to include ***every*** month
from Oct 2016 (`A2`) to Mar 2017 (`A23`),
including months that are not present in Column `A`,
you need to clarify the question.

### Either way,

To count the “Y” rows for each month, set `F2` to

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$99)=MONTH(E2)), --($C$2:$C$99="Y"))
```

and drag/fill down.

#### P.S. Diagnosis of failure

So you already understand the problem:
the last eight dates in Column `A` are in January, February and March (of 2017),
so they have `MONTH()` values of 1, 2 and 3. 
But when you use `MONTH(A2)+3`, etc., in `F5`, etc.,
you are counting rows that have `MONTH()` values of 13, 14 and 15
(which, of course, don’t exist). 
Once you have a list of months in Column `E`,
you should use those values in computing Column `F`.

Comment: In column `N`, the counts for Y/N are not correct. Please see the update to my question.